# Heroku, how to deploy Loopback app that is not in root directory of git repo?

Tags: heroku, vue.js, loopbackjs, webdeploy

I have my proyect in a subfolder (repo is the root folder repository in git)

```
/repo
  ../BackEnd  (loopback works with MySQL )
  ../FrontEnd (Vuejs)
```

First Create my App on heroku, then I link heroku with git (from dashboard of heroku web)

How I can tell to Heroku that my proyect is not in the root folder? The Folder that I want to link is BackEnd, where are the client folder and backend code.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "loopback"? What technology did you use to build `BackEnd`?

Comment: loopback is a framework in nodejs for create easy and fast api rest services